# Why do people use complicated functions to check a cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Does using document.cookies.includes("cookie=value") not do the trick? I see tons of complicated functions like:

```
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Why is this neccesary? Is there something wrong with checking for a cookie using document.cookie.includes()?

Comment: `String.prototype.includes` just checks whether a string is contained within the string instance the method is called on. This is not sufficient for cookies, as I could create a cookie with a value of "cookie=value", e.g. with `document.cookie = 'someCookieName=cookie=value'`.

Comment: Then couldn't i just use `string.prototype.includes('cookie=value')` to find whether it exists?